# ICE PDF | How to deploy and use with print option

Tags: java, pdf, ice

I am using icepdf - opensource java application for pdf viewer in my web.
ICEPDF works fine for me (I can view pdf using this) but now I want to add print option to this.
Is this possible. Is there any war file for this so that I will deploy it in tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

If your using the viewer as an Applet then you can use the "print" button on the toolbar to print.  If your using the ICEfaces webapp example or a variant of it then printing will be difficult via the browser.  The Servlet responsible for rendering a PDF page render a page at a time.  In order to print the whole document all pages in the document would have to be rendered to the browser before a print could be initiated.

Other PDF viewer web apps often push the print command off to a client side Applet or some native PDF viewer.

Comment: thank u so much. i am using icepdf viewer as applet. now i want to disable 'save-as' button from the toolbar available at the top.how to do that . please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

The PropertyManager class can be used to configure the UI.  Create a new instance, set the desired overrides and pass pass it into the SwingViewBuilder constructor.

```java
SwingController controller = new SwingController(); 

PropertiesManager properties =
    new PropertiesManager(System.getProperties(),
            ResourceBundle.getBundle(PropertiesManager.DEFAULT_MESSAGE_BUNDLE));

properties.setBoolean(PropertiesManager.PROPERTY_SHOW_UTILITY_SAVE,
            Boolean.FALSE);

SwingViewBuilder factory = new SwingViewBuilder(controller, properties);
```